# Many to many relation with multi column

Tags: php, mongodb

I use: Laravel mongodb (https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)

I have table relation in MySQL

table: *apps*

```
ID
Name
```

table: *clients*

```
ID
Name
```

And table relationship: *app_client*

```
app_id
client_id
version
```

field '*version*' in table *app_client* is string type

**How to create relational tables in MongoDB as containing the *version* column?**

I create table in Mongodb:
table: *apps*

```
ID
Name
client_ids => is array: [ObjectID('client_id'), ObjectID('client_id')]
```

table: *clients*

```
ID
Name
app_ids => is array: [ObjectID('app_id'), ObjectID('app_id')]
```

But, not column *version*
Do you know what I mean? How to create column *version* in database mongodb?